# get results from multiple tables in mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am stack two days in solving this issues, 
I am trying to query more than one table table , and I want  to get all the result from the tables that match with my search criteria , I am trying to do something like this:

```
$queryz = "SELECT * FROM tbl_articles a, tbl_pages p 
WHERE a.title LIKE '%".$_GET["q"]."%' AND p.title LIKE '%".$_GET["q"]."%'";

if ($resultz = $mysqli->query($queryz))
{

    while ($rowz = $resultz->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
          echo "1</br>";
        }
    $resultz->free();
} 

$mysqli->close();
```

if my get is equal to "s" i must get a result, at least one (the number 1)... but i don't get result ! what to do ?

Comment: Refactor your code first

Comment: i sent in a $_GET["q"] a query......i cant get any results...i am trying to write a code but i dont know what code to write !

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Run this query: SELECT * FROM tbl_articles a, tbl_pages p WHERE a.title LIKE '%s%' AND p.title LIKE '%s%'

Comment: just not get any results !...but the results really exists in the DB

Comment: Did you run this query?

Comment: @AwladLiton yes,i didnt got any results more :\ ..

Comment: did you get any errors?

Comment: no...but no results...but i must got..because i have s

Comment: okay add some data in your question.

Comment: add some data from tbl_articles and tbl_pages tables in your question

Comment: i added...still didnt got any results :\

Comment: do you have another way to write my code with search in the two tables with echo the titles in the two tables ?

Comment: give some data from your database of tbl_articles.title and tbl_pages tables.title

Comment: i did...but still didnt got any results !

Comment: @Mikha Matta: if you can the talk to me in skype. my id is: awladnas

Comment: ok 1 minute i will add u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will give you result but you don't have relationship between two tables so you will not get result what you expected.

```
  $queryz = "SELECT * FROM tbl_articles a, tbl_pages p 
    WHERE a.title LIKE '%".$_GET["q"]."%' OR p.title LIKE '%".$_GET["q"]."%' order by a.id";

    if ($resultz = $mysqli->query($queryz))
    {

        while ($rowz = $resultz->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
              echo "1</br>";
            }
        $resultz->free();
    } 

    $mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

`WHEREa.title` -> `WHERE a.title` first of all!

You have missed a space!

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Comment: i tryed to , but still not got the results fine !...i got 2 results in stead of 4

Comment: Can't comment yet - not got 50 rep

Comment: Without seeing your data set I cannot tell whether this is the expected behaviour. Bare in mind that although there may be 4 records (2 in each database) you are only echoing 1 when it appears in BOTH databases

Comment: look , i want to search in 2 tables , the first tbl_pages and have "id,title" and the second tbl_articles and have "id,table,active" , i need to search the 2 tables...and i need to got in tbl_articles where title is LIKE search query AND the active=1 in this row,,,and in tbl_pages i need to get where title LIKE search query...and i need all the results one under one from the two tables

Comment: Ahhh - your original post did not say what you were trying to achieve it just showed your code which led me down the wrong path - "SELECT * FROM tbl_articles a, tbl_pages p 
WHERE a.title LIKE '%".$_GET["q"]."%' AND a.active = '1' OR p.title LIKE '%".$_GET["q"]."%'"